# Rails app already deployed to Heroku cannot be updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have successfully deployed by rails app to Heroku, no problems. But now I am unable to update it with changes that I make to my code. When I try:

```
git add .
git commit -m "asdasd"
git push heroku master
```

I am told:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'heroku/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I have tried Heroku ps, which gives me this:

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 541h 43m (98%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1)
web.1: up 2019/01/18 14:37:10 -0600 (~ 2m ago)
```

So it seems like nothing is really going on, and for some reason there is no way of reaching the heroku site through the cli. The logs don't show anything interesting, just simply fetching pages and the like.

The only other thing is that I changed the name of the site in the heroku website, and I think there was something I should have done in the cli, but now I've lost it. In the cli the name of the app is the same so I guess this isn't a problem.

Can anyone help? Much thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can search on the web interface settings your project's git repository url and check if is the same that your local remote has.

**.git/config**

```
[remote "heroku"]
        url = https://dir/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried 'heroku domains' which tells me the url is the same

Comment: So I guess the problem is something else!

Comment: Are you sure that when you made the commit you were on the master branch?

Comment: Yep, on branch master